# can't repeat the same function in several classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins

need to this code short .. 
this is numscroll plugin .. and i have many elements have data-number !!!

```
$(function(){

   $(".num1").numScroll({
      number: $(".num1").attr("data-number"),
      'time': 3000,
      'delay': 0
    });
    $(".num2").numScroll({
      number: $(".num2").attr("data-number"),
      'time': 3000,
      'delay': 0
    });
    $(".num3").numScroll({
      number: $(".num3").attr("data-number"),
      'time': 3000,
      'delay': 0
    });


})
```

Comment: It is not clear what exactly your attempting here. Could you clarify please.

Comment: @Itanex thanks bro it has been solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.each()` and a selector for all the classes.

```
$(".num1, .num2, .num3").each(function() {
    $(this).numScroll({
        number: $(this).data("number"),
        time: 3000,
        delay: 0
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much Barmar.. this is my first question here .. i was think no one will repeat ..  i am new in JavaScript .. thank you

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
$(function(){
   [".num1", ".num2", ".num3"].forEach((index)=>{
       $(index).numScroll({
           number: $(index).attr("data-number"),
           'time': 3000,
           'delay': 0
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro it has solved .. thanks for your beautiful answer